# Goal return mysql lastInsertId however insert is in a php function creating challenges

Tags: php, mysql

I need the value of lastInsertID to run a new query with the most recent insert however the challenge is that my insert is part of a php function. I don't know the correct way to return lastInsertID.

The input form redirects to index.php in which I have a switch that looks for the 'addClient' case, gets the data and then calls the function. The last row gets inserted twice

--update--
I determined when assigning the function to the var, the second entry is created. Any suggestions?

$displayLastID = addClient($clientOrgName, $clientContactFName, ...etc...) creates the second entry.

```
//here's my function


function addClient($clientOrgName, $clientContactFName, $clientContactLName, $clientContactEmail, $clientContactPhone, 
                    $clientOnsiteFName, $clientOnsiteLName, $clientOnsiteEmail, $clientOnsitePhone, $clientAddress1,                    
                    $clientAddress2, $clientCity, $clientState, $clientZipCode, $clientTaxExempt, $clientAccountNumber) {

    global $db; 
    $query = 'INSERT INTO client
                (client_org_name, client_contact_first_name, client_contact_last_name, client_contact_email,                
                client_contact_phone, client_onsite_first_name, client_onsite_last_name, client_onsite_email,               
                client_onsite_phone, client_address_1, client_address_2, client_city, client_state, client_zipcode,                 
                client_tax_exempt, client_account_number)
            VALUES
                (:clientOrgName,:clientContactFName,:clientContactLName,:clientContactEmail,
                :clientContactPhone,:clientOnsiteFName,:clientOnsiteLName,:clientOnsiteEmail,           
                :clientOnsitePhone,:clientAddress1,:clientAddress2,:clientCity,:clientState,:clientZipCode,
                :clientTaxExempt,:clientAccountNumber )';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientOrgName',$clientOrgName );
    $statement->bindValue(':clientContactFName',$clientContactFName );
    $statement->bindValue(':clientContactLName', $clientContactLName);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientContactEmail', $clientContactEmail);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientContactPhone', $clientContactPhone);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientOnsiteFName', $clientOnsiteFName);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientOnsiteLName', $clientOnsiteLName);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientOnsiteEmail', $clientOnsiteEmail);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientOnsitePhone', $clientOnsitePhone);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientAddress1', $clientAddress1);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientAddress2', $clientAddress2);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientCity', $clientCity);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientState', $clientState);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientZipCode', $clientZipCode);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientTaxExempt', $clientTaxExempt);
    $statement->bindValue(':clientAccountNumber', $clientAccountNumber);
    $statement->execute();
    $last_id = $db->lastInsertId(); //
    return $last_id;

}


//displays lastInsertId but runs the function twice

//so the last row is inserted 2x

case 'addClient':
        // Get the user data
        $clientOrgName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientOrgName');
        $clientContactFName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientContactFName');
        $clientContactLName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientContactLName');
        $clientContactEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientContactEmail');
        $clientContactPhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientContactPhone');
        $clientOnsiteFName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientOnsiteFName');
        $clientOnsiteLName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientOnsiteLName');
        $clientOnsiteEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientOnsiteEmail');
        $clientOnsitePhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientOnsitePhone');
        $clientAddress1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientAddress1');
        $clientAddress2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientAddress2');
        $clientCity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientCity');
        $clientState = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientState');
        $clientZipCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientZipCode');
        $clientTaxExempt = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientTaxExempt');
        $clientAccountNumber = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'clientAccountNumber');

        //  check inputs
        if ($clientOrgName == null || $clientContactFName == null ||
                $clientContactLName == null || $clientContactEmail == null || 
                $clientContactPhone == null || $clientAddress1 == null ||
                $clientCity == null || $clientState == null ||
                $clientZipCode == null || $clientTaxExempt == null) {
        $error = "Invalid data. Check all fields and try again.";
            include('../../errors/error.php');
        } else { 
        addClient($clientOrgName, $clientContactFName, $clientContactLName, $clientContactEmail, $clientContactPhone, 
                    $clientOnsiteFName, $clientOnsiteLName, $clientOnsiteEmail, $clientOnsitePhone, $clientAddress1,                    
                    $clientAddress2, $clientCity, $clientState, $clientZipCode, $clientTaxExempt, $clientAccountNumber);
        //header("Location: addOrder.php");
        $displayLastID = addClient($clientOrgName, $clientContactFName, $clientContactLName, $clientContactEmail, $clientContactPhone, 
                    $clientOnsiteFName, $clientOnsiteLName, $clientOnsiteEmail, $clientOnsitePhone, $clientAddress1,                    
                    $clientAddress2, $clientCity, $clientState, $clientZipCode, $clientTaxExempt, $clientAccountNumber);

        //header("Location: addOrder.php?clientID=$displayLastID");         
        echo $displayLastID;
        }

        break;
```

Comment: nothing in the above code runs the query twice, so it must be how the function is called.

Comment: `INSERT` statements don't open cursors so there's no need to close it

Comment: Thanks @Phil updating my code. I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: You are calling `addClient()` twice so what exactly did you expect to happen?

Comment: I’m trying to figure out how to get lastInsertID. I’m new to php. I’m figuring things out as I go.

Comment: Well right now you appear to be _calling_ the function twice - `addClient(…)`, and then `$displayLastID = addClient(…)` right after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see clearly what you want but even you do wrong this row should not inserted twice unless you have some conception mistake in your database. You have an *CLIENTONSITEMAIL and CLIENTONSITEPHONE* those columns should be *UNIQUE* right...?
I think your row was intersed twice because in your case you run it twice.

```
First : else { addclient(....
SECOND: $displayID= addclient(....
```

Your function returns a value that you need so you should use only the SECOND one.